# Does any bounded sequence of real numbers admit a nondecreasing convergent subsequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R$.

> $p\in\mathbb N$ is called a **peak** of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$a_p>a_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n>p\;.$$

If $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has finitely many peaks and $p\in\mathbb N$ is the largest peak of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then $$n_1:=p+1$$ is not a peak of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and hence $$a_{n_1}\le a_{n_2}\tag2$$ for some $n_2\in\mathbb N$. We can construct an increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ with $$a_{n_k}\le a_{n_{k+1}}\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N\tag3$$ in this way. On the other hand, if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has infinitely many peaks and $p_k\in\mathbb N$ is the $k$th peak of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then clearly $p_k<p_{k+1}$ and $$a_{p_k}>a_{p_{k+1}}\tag4$$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

> So, in any case, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ admits a monotone subsequence.

Now, suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$. The result above is used in the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to conclude that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ admits a (monotone) convergent subsequence.

> Is it even possible to find a *nondecreasing* convergent subsequence (even when $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has infinitely many peaks) in any case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certainly not.  For instance, let $(a_n)$ be any decreasing sequence.  Then every subsequence is also decreasing.